# Follow-up: create (grand)parent-child elements based on delimiter in attribute-values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Hereby a followup to a [question posted here last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425670/create-parent-child-elements-based-on-attribute-values-and-suppress-duplicate-el). 
Still being a newbie I'm struggling (again...) to transform - using XSLT 1.0 - the following XML which describes objects (note the slight change in the input - 'B.C.*' - to the previous question):

```
<Data>
    <Object>
        <Property Name="Id" Value="001"/>
        <Property Name="P.Id" Value="Id P"/>
        <Property Name="P.Description" Value="Descr P"/>
        <Property Name="A.Id" Value="Id A" />
        <Property Name="A.Description" Value="Descr A"/>
        <Property Name="B.Id" Value="Id B"/>
        <Property Name="B.Description" Value="Descr B"/>
        <Property Name="B.C.Id" Value="B.C.Id"/>
        <Property Name="B.C.Description" Value="B.C.Description"/>
    </Object>
</Data>
```

The following rules should apply to get the desired output:

1. For each 'Property'-element that does *not* contain separator '.' in the 'Name'-attribute, transform the 'Name'-attribute into a child-element and select the value of its 'Value'-attribute.
2. For each 'Property'-element that *does* contain separator(s) '.' in the 'Name'-attribute, create:

   - a) a (grand)parent element using 'substring-before' the separator in the 'Name'-attribute - 'recursively until the last occurence' (not sure how to describe; see desired output below), and
   - b) a child element using 'substring-after' the *last* separator in the 'Name'-attribute and select the value of its 'Value'-attribute.

The desired output should therefore look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <ObjectData>
        <Id>001</Id>
        <P>
            <Id>Id P</Id>
            <Description>Descr P</Description>
        </P>
        <A>
            <Id>Id A</Id>
            <Description>Descr A</Description>
        </A>
        <B>
            <Id>Id B</Id>
            <Description>Descr B</Description>
            <C>
                <Id>B.C.Id</Id>
                <Description>B.C.Description</C.Description>
            </C>
        </B>
    </ObjectData>
</Root>
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kPropertyByName" match="Property[contains(@Name, '.')]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', substring-before(@Name,'.'))"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Object">
        <ObjectData>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Property[not(contains(@Name, '.'))]"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="Property[generate-id(.) = 
                    generate-id(key('kPropertyByName',
                    concat(generate-id(..), '|', substring-before(@Name,'.')))[1])
                    ] ">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="parent"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </ObjectData>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Property[not(contains(@Name, '.'))]">
        <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Property[(contains(@Name, '.'))]" mode="parent">
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before(@Name,'.')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="child" select="../Property[
                substring-before(current()/@Name,'.') = 
                substring-before(./@Name,'.')]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Property[(contains(@Name, '.'))]" mode="child">
        <xsl:element name="{substring-after(@Name,'.')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives me the following output - having (unwanted) 'non-separated' C.*-elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <ObjectData>
        <Id>001</Id>
        <P>
            <Id>Id P</Id>
            <Description>Descr P</Description>
        </P>
        <A>
            <Id>Id A</Id>
            <Description>Descr A</Description>
        </A>
        <B>
            <Id>Id B</Id>
            <Description>Descr B</Description>
            <C.Id>B.C.Id</C.Id>
            <C.Description>B.C.Description</C.Description>
        </B>
    </ObjectData>
</Root>
```

Not what I'm looking for... Any help would be much appreciated again!

Comment: I don't think your output follows your rules. For example, you did **not** create a parent B element for `Name="B.C.Id"`; you used a previously created B element for `Name="B.Id"`. Unless you add some more constraints, this problem is not well defined.

Comment: It would also help knowing which specific XSLt 1.0 processor are you using. Since the input contains dot-delimited data (instead of proper XML markup), you could save a lot of work by using some extension functions - if your processor can support them.

Comment: Regarding your first remark, you are actually correct; sorry for that. Basically: elements need to be created hierarchically using the strings before/after the delimiter. If the string does not contain the delimiter, then create an element as-is. If a parent element 'to be created' already exists, then do not create it but do continue creating its child(ren) (rule 2). I hope this will clarify the problem.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 processor used is .NET's built-in one (XslCompiledTransform).

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar with MS processors; you'll have to lookup the documentation. FWIW, I have posted a solution that relies on some EXSLT extension functions. This is already quite complex; without these functions you are looking at an awful lot of work. For this you can thank the authors of the source document, who apparently don't have a clue about how to use XML.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem, but I have only time to solve it with XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
  <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="index" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-adjacent="tokenize(@Name, '\.')[$index]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(current-group()[2])">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[$index = count(tokenize(@Name, '\.'))]"/>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()[not($index = count(tokenize(@Name, '\.')))], $index + 1)"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="Object">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(*, 1)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Property[@Name]">
  <xsl:element name="{tokenize(@Name, '\.')[last()]}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution: it produces exactly the desired output. Unfortunately though, I'm limited to using XSLT 1.0...

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky and your processor supports the following EXSLT functions:

- exsl:node-set()
- str:tokenize()
- set:distinct()

then this might work for you:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" 
extension-element-prefixes="exsl set str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <Root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Object"/>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Object">
    <ObjectData>

        <xsl:variable name="nodes">
            <xsl:for-each select="Property">
                <xsl:variable name="value" select="@Value" />
                <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(@Name, '.')">
                    <node parent="{preceding-sibling::*[1]}">
                        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </node>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="nodes-set" select="exsl:node-set($nodes)/node" />

        <xsl:variable name="ancestors" select="set:distinct($nodes-set[not(string(@parent))])" />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="$ancestors">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes-set" select="$nodes-set"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </ObjectData>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node"> 
    <xsl:param name="nodes-set"/>
    <xsl:element name="{.}">
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="set:distinct($nodes-set[@parent=current()])" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@value"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$children">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes-set" select="$nodes-set"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@value">   
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result** (when tested with libxslt):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <ObjectData>
    <Id>001</Id>
    <P>
      <Id>Id P</Id>
      <Description>Descr P</Description>
    </P>
    <A>
      <Id>Id A</Id>
      <Description>Descr A</Description>
    </A>
    <B>
      <Id>Id B</Id>
      <Description>Descr B</Description>
      <C>
        <Id>B.C.Id</Id>
        <Description>B.C.Description</Description>
      </C>
    </B>
  </ObjectData>
</Root>
```